# Windows authentication (AD) not working when IIS Application pool is running as custom user

Tags: active-directory, iis, windows-authentication, application-pools

I'm using:

- Windows 10 x64 Professional (in ad domain)
- IIS 10
- Web site is running under local user EPM_USER, everything works except Windows authentication

Configuration:
[image]

When I try to from another computer which is also in AD domain with valid Active Directory, login fails:
[image]

If I change application pool that it runs under ApplicationPoolIdentity, than it works:

Comment: Why run IIS on a Windows 10 machine? Windows 10 is not intended to function as a server.

Comment: If you’re running the application pool under a local user it doesn’t have credentials on the domain. When you run it as the applicationpoolidentity it uses the network service account which is basically the machine’s AD account. Use that, or use a domain account to run the app pool in.

Comment: More info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/ check the `useKernelMode` setting.

Comment: And more detail about why this does or does not work… https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc758557(v=ws.10) Your SPN has to be configured properly to use a different account and it will not work with a local user account as mentioned. Kerberos has specific requirements.

Comment: @Davidw usually I would run IIS on Windows Server, but just for testing scenario I'm running it in vmware virtual machine.